# how to remove seperator from the end of a list python

Tags: python, list, separator

How can I remove the last separator from the end of a list?

Here's a function I created to place any separator between elements of a list.

```
def to_string(my_list, sep=' '):

    new_str = "List is: "

    index = 0
    for k in my_list:
        new_str = new_str + str(k) + sep
    return new_str

my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
string = to_string(my_list, sep='-')
print(string)
```

Current output:

```
List is: 1-2-3-4-5-
```

What I want it to be:

```
List is: 1-2-3-4-5
```

Comment: You can just `join`:  `print(','.join([1,2,3,4,5]))`

Comment: `print(string[:-1])` should do it

Comment: Both ways are working, is there any way to do this without slicing expressions? Or only using range()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `join()` method:

```
def to_string(my_list, sep=' '):
    return "List is: " + sep.join(map(str, my_list))
```

If you would like to use the range() function:

```
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    if i > 0:
        new_str += sep
    new_str += str(my_list[i])
```

This is unfortunately horribly un-Pythonic, and inefficient because Python has to copy into a new string for each `+` concatenation.

Comment: How can I do this with range() function only?

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to pick up the basic idea of how `range` would work within the function. I now understand there are much for efficient methods.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways! 
If you want to print you could use the `print` function:

```py
myList = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(*myList, sep=',')          #1,2,3,4,5         #or
print(*myList, sep=',', end=';') #1,2,3,4,5;        #if you like diferent ending...
```

`*` makes myList work as five separated arguments not as one list.

If you want a string you could use `str.join`

```py
myList = [1,2,3,4,5]
sep = ','
myString = sep.join(str(i) for i in myList) #The args need to be str
print(myString)  #1,2,3,4,5
```

But if you like it the hard way you have to change a little bit your function so it looks like:

```py
def to_string(my_list, sep=' '):
    new_str=str(my_list[0])
    for i in my_list[1:]: #Skip my_list[0]
        new_str += sep + str(i)
    return new_str
myList = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(to_string(myList, ',')) #1,2,3,4,5
```

**[Edit]**
Answering to @rks of course it is possible to use ranges:

```py
for i in range(1, len(my_list)): #Skip my_list[0]
    new_str += sep + str(my_list[i])
```

Comment: Is it possible to use the range() function as a pose to slicing? I know this is not preferred at all but I'm interested in finding out how to do it if it is possible. @DuniC

Comment: Thank you! All these have helped me understand a lot more! @DuniC

Answer (score 1):

Just return till array_length-len(sep), it should work

```
import StringIO

def to_string(my_list, sep=' '):
    new_str = StringIO.StringIO()
    new_str.write("List is: ")

    for k in my_list:
        new_str.write(str(k)+sep)
    result = new_str.getvalue()
    new_str.close()
    return result[:-len(sep)]

my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
string = to_string(my_list, sep='-')
print(string)
```

@Martjin peters thanks :)

Comment: This won't work with a separator two or more characters wide. Nor should you use concatenation like this *anyway*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters well I fixed it for separator length > 1, and ... could you please tell me why we should not be using concatenation like this?

Comment: Because you are creating a new string object each time. `str.join()` creates one new string object for the whole result, once.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for explanation :), Can I use StringIO here?

Comment: @NamitSingal If I wanted to use only the range() function is there any way to do this?

Comment: I am not sure of the way, but i think joeforker has given a pretty good solution :)

Comment: @NamitSingal: `StringIO` still does more concatenations than necessary. Fewer (things are buffered), but why use that when you have the whole input list already and just could calculate the output length in one go?

Answer (score 1):

Using the `join()` method is your best solution, but if you truly want to do it yourself, change your `return` to the following:

```
return new_str[:-len(sep)]
```

This will return a string consisting of the string you built *except for* the last character.

## Update

Thanks to Martijn Peters for pointing out that my original didn't deal correctly with separators of len > 1.

Comment: Note that using string concatenation in a loop like this is *really inefficient*. CPython has some optimisations that minimise the cost here, but you cannot count on that implementation detail.